# how do I scan all computers in my network with nmap?

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I am trying to use nmap to scan the computers on my network for conficker.  I am using Windows. What do I put in the target for all computer on a given subnet?

It is running: nmap -T4 -A -v

I put in 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.1.255 but it did not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nmap -PN -T4 -p139,445 -n -v --script=smb-check-vulns \ 
   --script-args safe=1 192.168.1.0/24
```

Answer (score 3):

192.168.1.0/24 is the subnet you need to specify if all the computers you want to reach are between 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.1.255.

Comment: Enough with the classes. Classful networking has been replaced ~15 years ago by CIDR.

Comment: There are no classes anymore. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR and, even better, http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Comment: /24 is CIDR notation.